# sorting numbers in a vector and print them in accening order

Tags: java

I want to make a sorting algorithm .. My vector should be printed in accending order .. I made this code but it does not work ...

```
public class User {

public static int[] sort(int[] a) {
    if (a == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i++] < a[i]) {
        int x= a[i];
        int y=a[i++];
        a[i++] =x;
        a[i] = y;
    } else {
        return a;
    }

}
    }
     return a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = { 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 1 };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(a)));

}
```

}

I am getting error output .. I got `[4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1]`

How to correct the code?

thanks

Comment: Your sorting loop just doesn't make sense. Well it make some senses, but there's a huge loophole there. Approaching this way, you're missing one loop inside. Imagine this: [101, 100, 1, 4, 6, 2, 1], right after the first swap, 100 stays firmly at the first position, no matter how you swap 101 with other numbers.

Comment: Sorting is a very basic and good programming exercise for beginners. Here's a nice starter pack for you: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/ . You can learn and get the concept much easier with the visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting algorithm is not implemented well.
Try this one:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
   for(int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
      if(a[j] < a[i]) {
          int x= a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = x;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public static int sort(int[] a) {
    if (a == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    ...

    return a;
```

to

```
public static int[] sort(int[] a) {
    if (a == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ...

    return a;
```

So that your method would return the whole array, not just a single value.

&

```
System.out.println(sort(a));
```

to

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(a)));
```

So as to print the array correctly.

**EDIT:**

You can get your array sorted simply by using [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])):

```
int a[] = { 4, 6, 8, 2, 4, 1 };
Arrays.sort(a);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Comment: Change it to `return null;`

Comment: I did not check how you sort the array.. but you could simply sort the array by calling `Arrays.sort()` & pass in the array.